# Solving the equation $x^2-2x+2$ by completing the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I started solving this three part question that asks to solve the equation: $x^2-2x+2=0$

I used the completing the square method and found the two solutions: $x=1+i$ and $x=1-i$

Then the other questions ask if the solutions are real or complex and how many distinct solutions are there. I'm not sure how to tell if the solutions are real or complex (or if the i makes it complex). For the Last question, do I use the formula (don't know how to type out the radical sign) $b^2-4ac$ to find the number of solutions?

Answer (score 1):

1. The $i$ does indeed make it complex.
2. You already found the two solutions when you completed the square, so you don't need to bother with $b^2-4ac$ to know that there are two distinct solutions.

Note that in general, $b^2-4ac$ (the *discriminant* of the quadratic equation) does tell you how many distinct solutions there are, and whether they are real or complex:

- if $b^2-4ac>0$, there are two distinct real solutions;
- if $b^2-4ac=0$, there is one real solution (and no complex solutions);
- if $b^2-4ac<0$, there are no real solutions (and two distinct complex solutions).

Note also that this is valid only for quadratics with real coefficients (as in your example).

Answer (score 0):

You're solution is correct. I made a mistake in my original answer. The above is not a perfect square. The quadratic equation is the quickest way to solve this.

## Edit

$$(x-(1+i))(x-(1-i))=x^2-x(1-i)-x(1+i)+(1+i)(1-i)=x^2-2x+2$$

Comment: Oh, now I see my mistake. I'm just not sure if the solutions are real or complex.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand it! Now I see what I did wrong.

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote/accept the answer if you're all good.

Comment: I'm not sure how I write out the solutions. I don't know how to write the multiplicity as a solution.

Comment: The solutions are $x=1+i,1-i$ with mutliplicty 1. That's all yo need to write

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance. The solutions are still real, but I'm not sure how to plug it into the equation to verify that it's correct with the i

Comment: The solutions are complex and there are two of them

Comment: My mistake, I was still referring to the one without a correction. I'm not sure if my arithmetic is right for verifying the solution.

Comment: See my addition above

Answer (score 0):

1. They are complex due to the **i**
2. There are 2 distinct solutions as you have found: 1 - **i** and 1 + **i**